# inject Image without removing src attribute

Tags: dart, dart-html

is there a way to inject HTML without filtering the src attribute in Dart (no security needed in context), I've tried setInnerHtml, but it doesn't let src pass it...

here's the div I'm adding html in:

```
<div id="output">
    <!--here goes messages-->

</div>
```

here's my dart code:

```
import 'dart:html';
import 'dart:async';

InputElement input = querySelector("#textInput");
var output = querySelector("#output");
var buttonSend = querySelector("#send");
var buttonImg = querySelector("#url");
var buttonVideo = querySelector("#video");

Future<Null> main() async {

  //send custom message
  buttonSend.onClick.listen((MouseEvent event) async{
    addContent(input.value);
  });

  //send img
  buttonImg.onClick.listen((MouseEvent event) async{
    addContent(getPrefabImg(input.value));
  });

  //send video
  buttonVideo.onClick.listen((MouseEvent event) async{
    addContent(getPrefabVideo(input.value));
  });
}

//if user use a prefab img
String getPrefabImg(url) {
  return "<img class='prefabImg' src='" + url + "'>";
}


//if user use a prefab video
String getPrefabVideo(url) {
  return "<iframe class='prefabVideo'' src='" + url + "' frameborder='0' allowfullscreen></iframe>";
}


//reset input and add content
void addContent(value){
  output.setInnerHtml(value + output.innerHtml);
  input.value = null;
 }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To create and inject HTML into the DOM without a `NodeTreeSanitizer`, you will need to switch from using HTML `String`s to using Dart's `Node` objects. Picking a couple of functions from your code as an example, you can change them to something like;

```
ImageElement getPrefabImg(String url) {
  return new ImageElement(src: url)..classes.add('prefabImage');
}

void addContent(Node node) {
  output.nodes.insert(0, node);
  input.value = null;
}
```

But with your current code you can easily add a `NodeTreeSanitizer` like so;

```
void addContent(String value) {
  output.insertAdjacentHtml(
      'afterBegin', value, treeSanitizer: NodeTreeSanitizer.trusted);
  input.value = null;
}
```